# jqGrid Memory leak on reloadGrid in IE6 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, memory-leaks, jqgrid

I am trying to reload the `jqGrid` but at every `reload trigger of jqGrid` The memory used by the `IE6` browser is increased and browser is hanged for some time. I also tried in my mobile, my mobile is hanged and the takes some time to load the `jqGrid Data` and after many time of `reload` the `jqGrid` my mobile browser become to die.

`jqGrid Version`: 4.4.3

`jquery Version`: 1.7.2

`jquery UI version`: 1.8.24

First I made the request to `server` for the data with `jquery` post and after that I passed that `data` to `jqGrid` to fill.

My code:

```
$.post(this.actionURL, this.postData, function (data) {
//my function is called to fill the jqGrid
}
```

Create the `jqGrid` if not exist:

```
this.jqGridView.jqGrid({
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            datastr: data,
            loadui: "block",
            jsonReader: { "repeatitems": false },
            colNames: this.columnNames,
            colModel: this.columnModel,
            height: "auto",
            gridview: true,
            rowNum: '',
            ignoreCase: true,
            forceFit: true,
            autowidth: false,
            width: this.jqGridViewWidth,
            loadComplete: function () {
            }
        });
```

Reload the `jqGrid` if th `jqGrid` is exist:

```
 this.jqGridView.jqGrid("clearGridData");
        this.jqGridView.jqGrid('setGridParam',
            {
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                datastr: data
            })
            .trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Problem:

1. Memory used by the browser is increased at every time reload of the jqGrid.
2. Can we clear the jqGrid data after the jqGrid is displayed on the screen? So the memory can become the clean and the jqGrid still display the data.

Comment: jqGrid version 4.4.3 is **too old** is dead since a long time. It's not supported. The retro web browser IE6 is not supported too. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, My whole application runs on the `jqGrid 4.4.3` and I have to give the support in `IE6`. Some time ago I don't know but however I got the `OutOfMemoryException`. Please help me If you know any way to handle this `Memory Leak`.

Comment: I have no computer to test IE6 and even to test IE8. So I really can't help you if I would want to try it. Old IE version have absolutely another memory management, which was difficult to manage. Moreover debugging of memory leaks in IE is really complex job and fixing of the problem could be only in changing some places of code of 4.4.3, which is dead too. You use just too old systems, which are dead. The only way to clean the memory is **reloading of the page** with respect of `location.reload();`

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, I will try and I informed you If I got the success. Once again Thanks.

Comment: One more question @Oleg. `jqGrid 4.4.3` really have the `Memory Leak` issue ?

Comment: You are welcome! I have to add that holding computers with IE6 now is a large strategic error. It's almost the same as usage Window NT 3.5 or IE3. If one have to hold some old systems for some time then one have to use Google Chrome or Firefox web browsers. I'm not sure which operation system you use, but you can sure find a version of Chrome or Firefox, which can be installed on the old systems. You will have **much more better** performance and much less problems with memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, jqGrid 4.4.3 should have Memory Leak issues **in old web browsers** (old IE).

Comment: Which operation system you use?

Comment: I am developing the application in `asp.net C# .NET 4.5 in Windows 8.1`. But I testing my app in the `Windows XP SP3` in `IE6` browser through the `virtual machine`.

Comment: I deleted such old virtual machines. Look at the URL http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-browser_version-ww-monthly-201605-201605-bar . You will see that IE8 be used only on 1.28% **desktop** computers in the world (and 1.25 in India). IE6 is practically not exist more. If one take in consideration all systems (not only desktops) then IE8 will be not listed at all.

Comment: @Oleg, Thanks man for the help and information. Any way I have to fix this bug and submit this to my company.

Comment: You are welcome! You can just forward to your company the recommendation to take in consideration only IE8 and no more IE7 or IE6. I'd recommend you **don't use retro version jqGrid 4.4.3**. You can upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.3. It's the fork, which I develop. It you will find some bug in the version I can help to fix it. It should still work with jQuery 1.7.2 and it works on **the same web browsers like the version 4.4.3 do**.

Comment: Okay @Oleg, Thank You. I will inform my company about this issue.